# Allow only a specific ip address to an open port

Tags: 14.04, firewall

I have a Zimbra server and the admin port, 7071, is open to the world. I had someone try to get into it yesterday and that locked the account.

I was wondering if I can block all access to this port with the exception of a few ip addresses to allow me in.

deny all/allow ip range?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use iptables for this

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7071 -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7071 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll read up on iptables as I'm not that familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `ufw` worked better than `iptables`. I was using Ubuntu `18.04`.

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow from 1.2.3.4 to any port 7071
sudo ufw deny 7071
```